# Shortcut for Windows 7 Registry entry

Tags: windows-registry, shortcuts

Take for example this Registry entry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services`

..or some other deeply nested (more than 6 levels) entry.

If I frequently modify the entries inside that, I find it difficult to navigate to that entry every single time.

Is there a way in which I can put a shortcut or something in my desktop for that entry so that when I open it, I am taken directly to that registry entry?

Comment: Registry should remember your last viewed key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Regedit's toolbar there should be a "favourites" entry. This works very much like favourites in your internet browser, you can add the current location to your favourites, or instantly navigate to any location you have saved previously. You can also give your favourites custom names so you can remember them more easily.